# AutoMapping objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a weird situation where I have `object`s and `List`s of `object`s as part of my entities and contracts to interface with a third-party service.  I'm going to try to see if I can replace the actual object class with something more specific in the entities and contracts to get around this, but I am curious if there is a way to get AutoMapper to handle this as is.

Here are some dummy classes:

```
public class From
{
    public object Item { get; set; }
}

public class FromObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class To
{
    public object Item { get; set; }
}

public class ToObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the quick replication:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<From, To>();
Mapper.CreateMap<FromObject, ToObject>();

From from = new From { Item = new FromObject { Value = "Test" } };
To to = Mapper.Map<To>(from);
string type = to.Item.GetType().Name; // FromObject
```

Basically, the question is this:  Is there a way to get AutoMapper to understand that `from.Item` is a `FromObject` and apply the mapping to `ToObject`?  I'm thinking there's probably not a way to make it automatic, since there's nothing that would indicate that `to.Item` has to be a `ToObject`, but is there a way to specify during the `CreateMap` or `Map` calls that this should be taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an *"automatic"* way of doing it, since `AutoMapper` won't be able to figure out that `From.Item` is `FromObject` and `To.Item` is `ToObject`.

But, while creating mapping, you can specify that

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FromObject, ToObject>();
Mapper.CreateMap<From, To>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Item, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<ToObject>(src.Item)));            

From from = new From { Item = new FromObject { Value = "Test" } };
To to = Mapper.Map<To>(from);
string type = to.Item.GetType().Name; // ToObject
```

Comment: That works, but requires that `To.Item` is always `ToObject`, which is limiting.

Comment: Yes, that is limiting, but that's how `AutoMapper` works. It maps `type-to-type`, and we need a mapping from `TypeA` to `TypeB`. If we do not know the type at compile time, I'm not sure if we can create a map.

Comment: I've added an answer that adds flexibility but requires an additional interface to achieve.  I think you're right that there's no way to do it without - I tried doing `<object, object>` and it doesn't work correctly (maps to `object`).

Comment: @zimdanen with the introduction of the interface, it increases the complexity (a bit), and also creates a new type of restriction on the types (they have to implement that interface). It is an interesting approach, but the original problem remains unresolved!

Comment: Agreed!  Neither is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use an additional interface, this can be accomplished using `Include`.  You can't just map `object` to `object` in this fashion, though.

```
public class From
{
    public IItem Item { get; set; }
}

public class FromObject : IItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class To
{
    public object Item { get; set; }
}

public class ToObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IItem
{
    // Nothing; just for grouping.
}

Mapper.CreateMap<From, To>();
Mapper.CreateMap<IItem, object>()
    .Include<FromObject, ToObject>();

From from = new From { Item = new FromObject { Value = "Test" } };
To to = Mapper.Map<To>(from);
string type = to.Item.GetType().Name; // ToObject
```